# How to add another object to an object array

Tags: java, arrays

i have java code (array of objects)

```
 Items[] store = new Items[] { new Items(...) , new Items(...) };
```

What is the standard method to  append to this store array. I am trying not to use ArrayList or other convenient methods for a start. thanks

Comment: You cannot resize an array: once it's made you'll have to overwrite it with a new one. That's why you're advised to use an `ArrayList` which allows easy resizing in your collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is not to use an array, but rather an `ArrayList<Items>` which behaves much like an array that can grow or shrink as needed. Then you can simply call `myList.add(myItem)` to append to it.

If this won't work for you, then please share the details of your requirements.

---

**Edit**
You state in an edit:

> I am trying not to use ArrayList or other convenient methods for a start.

Please tell us why the stipulation? If you want an array to grow, you'll have to create a *new* array that is larger than the previous, copy all items to it, and add the new item. It's a lot of work that ArrayList does for you.

Comment: ok. thanks. that's troublesome. Ok i will try to use ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Items items1=new Items();
Items items2=new Items();

......
ArrayList<Items> listItems=new ArrayList<Items>();
listItems.add(items1);
listItems.add(items2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
store = Arrays.copyOf(store, store.length +1);
store[store.length - 1] = newItem;
```